# Unable to add shapefiles via drag and drop - QGIS 2.4 OSx

Tags: qgis, osx, drag-and-drop

I have a clean install of OSx Yosemite Beta 5, with homebrew install of QGIS 2.4 and all its basic dependencies.

-QGIS version    2.4.0-Chugiak
   -QGIS code revision  exported 
   -Compiled against Qt 4.8.6
   -Running against Qt  4.8.6 
   -Compiled against GDAL/OGR   1.11.1
   -Running against GDAL/OGR    1.11.1 
   -Compiled against   GEOS 3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2
   -Running against GEOS    3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2 r3921
   -PostgreSQL Client Version   9.3.5
   -SpatiaLite Version  4.2.0 
   -QWT   Version   6.1.1
   -PROJ.4 Version  480 
   -QScintilla2 Version 2.8.3

Am able to load QGIS with no errors thrown, and can view shapefiles, connect to postgres, etc, but can only add new shapefiles if done through the 'Layer - Add Vector Layer' workflow.  Dragging and dropping into QGIS results in:

- 'Invalid Data Source:/.file/id=6571367..... is not a valid or
  recognized data source

I am also unable to use SPIT to import shapefiles into postgres:

- Problem inserting features from file:/xxxxx/xx.shp

Comment: Why did you use Yosemite (beta for developers) and not a stable version (Mavericks for example ?)

Comment: I'm getting the same error when dragging and dropping files onto QGIS 2.8 installed using homebrew on 10.10.2 (which is now stable)

Comment: QGIS bug report is here (https://hub.qgis.org/issues/11399) but this appears to be a bug in Qt rather than QGIS specifically (https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-40449).